# Passing a long html code to a new page in Razor MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

[image: My View page]

I have a page displaying some html codes in a `Textarea`. I want to allow users to click on `ViewHTML` which should display the decoded version of the html text into a preview page.

What I can't figure out it is, how do I pass the html code as a string on a new page as it contents unicode ?

My view code:

`@Html.ActionLink("View HTML", "HtmlViewer",null, new { target = "_blank", html = Model.EmailTemplate.EmailBodyText }, null)`

Comment: Could you pass it up to a Controller Action as a parameter, then return it back down with AJAX; Or why not just do a replace with JQuery or Javascript to update a div somewhere with its contents? That sounds a little dangerous though

Comment: I don't understand what your asking for. It appears that the textarea contains the "decoded HTML." Are you trying to provide a preview feature?

Comment: @James I understand it's little dangerous however this is an internal application with very few users.... Replacing with jQuery sounds like a good idea however, it wouldn't be neat as it's a big html

Comment: @JeremyCook yes, a preview feature

Comment: @YagneshCangi if you pass it up to a Controller Action first, you can santise the input to be sure nothing dodgy is in there. Then pass it back with ajax. Its an extra transaction but gives you a little security. Dont under estimate how many internal users can be threats

Comment: This seems very very danagerous - kind of what Markdown was invented for?

Comment: @James how do I santise the input? I'm very new to razor and mvc so please bare with me

Comment: Then "View HTML" seems to be a misnomer, "Preview Email" would make more sense to me. Beyond that, you could either get fancy with javascript and ajax, or you could keep things simpler and simply have two buttons for submitting the form, one name "Preview Email" another named "Finish" (or whatever). Clicking the preview button will post back the form and update the preview. Clicking the finish button would do whatever you need.

Comment: By santise I mean strip out any nasty things such as script tags.

Comment: How to sanitize HTML has been answered elsewhere on stack overflow. Also, **Markdown was not invented to sanitize HTML**. Not all Markdown libraries are equal, sanitization of HTML may be an option of a particular Markdown library or may be something you have to do in addition to using that library.

Comment: The email HTML is actually coming from a database. If I pass in the GUID into my controller, get the html code within the controller and pass it to the view as a string.... Is this safe or do I still need to sanititze HTML?